# Compilation errors on sample USB project for MPLAB

Tags: compiler-errors, usb, microcontroller, pic, mplab

I'm using mplab ide 8.43, and I've downloaded **Microchip Application Libraries v2011-12-05 Windows** from [here](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en547784).

I haven't changed any of the compiler settings.  I'm using the **HI-TECH Universal toolSuite** to build the project.

When trying to compile the **pic18f starter kit 1** sample project I get a number of warnings and errors which I've put [here](http://pastebin.com/a7pn5V1a).

I've tried other sample projects from the same page and tried other toolchains (some of which produced different errors), to no avail.

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest you add more detail about exactly how you set up your project, maybe with some code. Have you got any samples to compile?

Answer (score 0):

I'm nowhere near a PIC/MPLAB installation right now but ... looking at your error log you are using the Hi-tech compiler (PICC18). These libraries are almost certainly written for Microchip's own C18 compiler.

And yes, Hi-tech is owned by Microchip.

And **yes** the two are not compatible. They use different header files, for example.

Download a "free trial" of the C18 compiler from [here](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en010014) and try building using that.